# Importing names from an aliased module. Is it possible?

Tags: python, python-import

When I try to do the following construction in Python, I get, `"No module named foo"` **on the second line**

```
import my_package.my_very_long_module_name as foo
from foo import f1, f2, f3
from foo import a, b, c
from foo import x, y, z
```

`my_very_long_module_name` is a module (`my_very_long_module_name.py`) within the folder `my_package` (the folder has the file `__init__.py`).

Why does the second line above fail? Am I not allowed to import names from an aliased module?

If that construction is not legal in Python, is there any other way to do this? (

Comment: eh! you cannot use variable names in `import` statement. It'll try to find a module named `foo.py(c)` here.

Comment: Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary. I take then that I can't use module aliases in `from X import Y` statements? No workarounds?

Comment: try: `from my_package.my_very_long_module_name import function_1, function_2, function_3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import my_package.my_very_long_module_name as foo
from foo import f1, f2, f3
```

The second line fails because python will try to find a module name `foo.py`, it won't use the variable `foo` you just imported.

You can try something like this:

```
import my_package.my_very_long_module_name as foo
f1, f2, f3 = foo.f1, foo.f2, foo.f3
del foo
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is correct that you cannot use variables in import statements, you can simply access the variables of the module.

Thus, you can do:

```
a = foo.a
```

And you can even write to `globals` if you insist. Honestly, though, I encourage you to just use the qualified `foo.a` in your code. It'll make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be done my modifying the sys.modules dictionary.

```
import sys
import my_package.my_very_long_module_name as foo

sys.modules['foo'] = foo
from foo import f1, f2, f3
from foo import a, b, c
from foo import x, y, z
```

*Warning*: Doing this registers `foo` globally for this python session, so any other modules that try to `import foo` will end up with the `my_package.my_very_long_module_name`

For your particular case this is probably a bad way to go about this because of the global impact.  This can however be useful when a global rename is desired.